# How do I disable mobile,email in razorpay payment process

Tags: payment-gateway, razorpay

I'm new to razorpay payment gateway. Here already implementation done. Menas payment is happening by taking Email and Phone number. But as per new requirement I want to remove Mobil,Email in payment process. Where can I disable it? Can I disable Razorpay to asking Email and Phone number. Thank you

Comment: hi @Kodali444 did you find any solution to this problem of razorpay?

Answer (score 3):

I used 'prefill' so automatically those values are populating on Razorpay form. So I no need to enter second time there.

```
    var options = {
        "key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "amount": Amount * 100, // 2000 paise = INR 20
        "name": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
        "description": "Purchase Description",
        "handler": function (response) {

        },
        "prefill": {
                   "email": "abc@gmail.com",
                   "contact": "8888888888"
              }
    };
    var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
    rzp1.open();
```

Comment: But even this prefilled values can be edited by customer. Is it possible to disable customer from editing

Comment: I didn't try that one. Because in my case we didn't have that requirement. did you try in Razorpay document? I think i found the above solution there only

Comment: Yes, You can use 
readonly: {
email: true,
contact: true
} to make your fields readonly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dummy value and set the email to read-only. Worked in my case.

```
options = {
      'key': 'rzp_test_B9*********',
      'amount': totalAmount,
      'name': "name",
      'order_id': orderId,
      'description': 'Payment',
      'prefill': {'contact': '999999999', 'email':'test@example.com'},
      "readonly": { 'email': true, 'contact': true },
      'external': {
        'wallets': ['paytm']
      },
    }
```

Comment: what if user will choose to pay with mobikwik, or other wallet to which phone number otp will be sent