# How to remove email id field in razorpay payment process

Tags: payment-gateway, razorpay

The razorpay payment implementation has already been done. Payment is happening by taking email and phone number. But now I need to remove email id field. I checked rayzorpay docs but couldn't find it. How can I remove it?

Comment: Did you find any way to do that? I need to do the same.

Comment: Not yet.. @Newbie

Comment: I talked to their support. They said you could fill them with any dummy email. I did that and also set it to readonly. Works for my use case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disable mobile,email in razorpay payment process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60211341/how-do-i-disable-mobile-email-in-razorpay-payment-process)